# How to plot the frequency of values by day with pandas and plotly?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I would like to plot a bar chart using pandas and plotly that shows the frequency of players by day while at the same time, I can filter bars shown by Level so there has to be a "Level Legend" on the graph for me to filter the result shown. I would also like all the 7-days to be shown on the x-axis in an orderly manner. Help is much appreciated!

Below is my code:

```
# data lists
day = ['Monday','Wednesday','Sunday','Wednesday']
level = ['Level 5','Level 2','Level 1','Level 2']
score = ['50','20','10','25']
player = ['Tom','Sam','Bill','Max']

# create new dataframe and insert desired columns
df = pd.DataFrame({'day':day,
                    'level':level,
                    'score':score,
                    'player':player})
df
```

I'd like the output to be something like this:
[image: Plot of Player Frequency by Date]

Comment: I understand what you're aiming for here. But the provided dataset is too limited to make any interesting out of it. As soon as you start filtering anything here you quickly just end up with the count of one player for one day of the week. Would you care to expand your dataset a bit?

Comment: apologies for that. Thank you for your time answering! The solution is exactly what i need

Comment: No worries! Happy to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete snippet below will filter your dataset by levels using buttons, and display count of players by day on the x-axis. The essence of how this is done is:

1. Set day as an ordered cateogory using `pd.Categorical(df['day'], categories=new_order, ordered=True)`,
2. split the data by `df['level'].unique()` and assign traces using `fig.add_bar()`,
3. set the visibilty of each trace through `visibility = [list(s) for s in [e==1 for e in np.eye(len(levels))]]`

#### Plot 1

[image]

#### Plot 2

[image]

As you can see I've added a few details to your dataset to make it a *bit* more interesting.

#### Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# data lists
day = ['Monday','Wednesday','Sunday','Wednesday', 'Tuesday']
level = ['Level 5','Level 2','Level 1','Level 2', 'Level 2']
score = ['50','20','10','25', '25']
player = ['Tom','Sam','Bill','Max', 'Sam']

# create new dataframe and insert desired columns
df = pd.DataFrame({'day':day,
                    'level':level,
                    'score':score,
                    'player':player})

# plotly setup
fig = go.Figure()

# data management
# - grouping
# - setiing up visibility attributes for groups
# - treat days as categorical variable
levels = df['level'].unique()[::-1]
nlevels = len(levels)
visibility = [list(s) for s in [e==1 for e in np.eye(len(levels))]]

new_order = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
df['day'] = pd.Categorical(df['day'], categories=new_order, ordered=True)

buttons = [] # container for buttons in updatemenu

# split data by levels,
# and add button per level
# with counts of players per day
# in an orderly fashion
for i, l in enumerate(levels):
    ds = df[df['level']==l]
    dg = ds.groupby('day').agg({'player':'count'}).reset_index()

    fig.add_bar(x = dg['day'], y = dg['player'],
                visible=True if l=='Level 1' else False)
    
    
    # one button per dataframe to trigger the visibility
    # of all columns / traces for each dataframe
    button =  dict(label=l,
                   method = 'restyle',
                   args = ['visible',visibility[i]])
    buttons.append(button)

# include dropdown updatemenu in layout
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=[dict(type="dropdown",
                                    direction="down",
                                    buttons = buttons)])
    
fig.show()
```